# Meaningful thumbnails for a Video using PHP-FFMpeg (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, laravel-5, video-thumbnails

I'm working on a project using Laravel 5 and the [PHP-FFmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) Library.

Previously someone else asked this question "[Meaningful thumbnails for a Video using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/538112/meaningful-thumbnails-for-a-video-using-ffmpeg)" that works from the command line.

However, I want to implement the functional equivalent using the PHP-FFmpeg Library.

I have scanned both Stack Overflow and the Unit Tests for PHP-FFmpeg to try and figure out the correct syntax, but it is just not jumping out at me.

So I'm hoping someone with more experience with PHP-FFmpeg can give me some pointers or an example of how to achieve the same results as the command line calls referenced in this post: "Meaningful thumbnails for a Video using FFmpeg".

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

BTW, This is my first post on Stack Overflow so the site won't let me post all the relevant links (limit 2) or create a tag for "PHP-FFmpeg".

Comment: why dont you use exec() function of php to execute linux command through php and save the thumbnail to your desired location directly

Comment: you can just `exec` the command you want with out the need for `PHP-FFmpeg`

Comment: I'm well aware of the PHP exec() function and yes I could potentially use it.  However, That was not my question.  My question was what is the functional equivalent using the PHP-FFmpeg Library...

Answer (score 1):

This might help https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP (refer to the section Wrapper Libraries at the bottom of the page).